# Does it make to sense to derive a new column based on quantiles?

Tags: discrete-data, binning

I am working with a dataset with alcohol levels. It looks something like this:

```
Alcohol Level
10.34
3.21
323.12
...
```

I'm wondering whether it is common to "bin" these alcoholic levels into bins based on their quantiles (thereby, converting numerical to categorical):

```
Alcohol Level
moderate alcoholic
not really alcoholic
super alcoholic
...
```

I think this would simplify my analysis, but I don't know what assumptions I've just made! The quantile amount is arbitrary. I'm wondering whether this is statistically valid.

Comment: This is an example of binning. It is quite frequent in statistics. One reason is in preparing tables of frequencies, where concise presentation and/or preservation of confidentiality may require coarsening of information. Another reason is for classed choropleth (patch) maps. Yet another reason, which I hear of repeatedly in microecomonics and finance, is that researchers like to think about the 10% best (worst) performing stocks, firms, etc., etc. One enormous reason never to do it is that it discards precious detail and possibly structure in the data.

Comment: Be careful of the distinction between "what is common" and what is a good idea. Many things are commonly done that are not useful/sensible.

Comment: @Glen_b That was what I was scared about. Sorry if this is a beginner question. It seems fairly sketchy to just "bin" and assign labels.

Comment: I wasn't trying to take a position on your question nor indeed to criticize asking a beginner question\*, so much as asking you to clarify which of the two distinct things you sought -- it may be you want what is commonly done or you may want what makes sense -- if you're trying to justify something to a less knowledgeable referee for example, "what is commonly done" may be a more viable strategy than doing what makes sense. $\quad$  \* beginner questions are *completely* welcome, if they otherwise satisfy the requirements for a question. This question is not a facile one, though.